# При использовании литерала ' перед русским символом вылетает ошибка

Tags: c++, xcode

Вылетает ошибка: "Character too large for enclosing character literal type"
/"Символ слишком большой для включения символьного литерала"

```
string str_Word;
getline(cin, str_Word);
int int_LastSymbol = str_Word.length();
if (str_Word[int_LastSymbol] == 'й') { //тут ошибка

}
```

Я понял, что  ошибка в кодировке файла, если не так то поправьте, но как ее изменить я так и не понял: c++, xcode.

Comment: Надо полагать, у вас кодировка utf-8? В этой кодировке один символ может занимать до  6 байт, соответственно проверка одного символа сводится к проверке наличия подстроки. А буквенные литералы и индексирование в строках по сути полноценно использоваться не могут.

Comment: Повторюсь, с английскими символами проблемы не возникает, следовательно проблема в кодировке. Как ее изменить?

Comment: Английские символы (ASCII, если точнее) занимают в UTF-8 только один байт и с ними все это хозяйство работает нормально.